# Service can't start on boot but can start on manual

Tags: python, service, pyinstaller

I have python project using servicemanager and I use pyinstaller to build it as exe. Everything work fine and I have install it as window service.

I have set services startupType: Automatic(Delayed start).

But when I reboot computer the services is not start and I have to go to services and start it manual.

I check event viewer and it say:

```
The instance's SvcRun() method failed 
<Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed 
%2: %3
```

This is my code:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
(r'/', WebSocketHandler),
])

class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "SignMatchService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "SignMatchService"
    _svc_description_ = "The service match signature"

    def log(self, msg):
        import servicemanager
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(str(msg))

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(150)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        _init_asyncio_patch()
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        global sig_matcher
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        try:
            self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
            _init_asyncio_patch()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
            app.listen(5555)
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
            win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)
        except Exception as x:
            print('Exception : %s\n' % x)
            self.SvcStop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

Comment: this looks like it might be relevant (see comment on issue) https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1148

Comment: I have test service manager with tcp socket and it work fine. Service start when reboot. Maybe the problem is tornado or asyncio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for wrong information. Error above is old error when i test service.

Error is:

`A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the TestService service to connect.`

And increase timeout for window service will solve the problem